# char Array to string conversion results in strange characters - sockets

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server

I currently have the following code

```
char my_stream[800];
std::string my_string; 
iResult =  recv(clntSocket,my_stream,sizeof(my_stream),0);
my_string = std::string(my_stream);
```

Now when I attempt to convert the char array to string I get the present of weird characters in the string any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong

Comment: what's `tick_stream`?  and `my_string` is an array of characters you're trying to reassign?

Comment: just updated the code. Need to convert char array to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting weird characters because your strings length is not equal to the number of bytes received.

You should initialize the string like so:

```
char* buffer = new char[512];

ssize_t bytesRead = recv(clntSocket,buffer,512,0);

std::string msgStr = std::string(buffer,bytesRead);

delete buffer;
```

The most common solution is to zero every byte of the buffer before reading anything.

```
char buffer[512];
buffer = { 0 };
```

Comment: Be sure to check the actual value of `bytesRead` first. It will be `-1` on error and `0` on disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading in a zero-terminated string from your socket, there's no need for a conversion, it's already a char string.  If it's not zero-terminated already, you'll need some other kind of terminator because sockets are streams (assuming this is TCP).  In other words, you don't need `my_string = std::string(my_stream);`

Comment: The incoming string may contain '\n' in it and I want that to be present in the resulting string

Comment: Ok, the `iResult` you get back is the length received... you can zero-terminate it by doing `my_stream[iResult] = 0;`  But you need to make sure you have room for the extra 0 "character"... you can do it like this: `recv(clntSocket,my_stream,sizeof(my_stream)-1,0);`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to print my_stream directly without converting to string. 
According to me it may be the case of mismatch in format of data sent and received.
data on other side may be in other format like Unicode and you may be trying to print it as single byte array
if only part of string is in weird characters than it is definitely error related to null terminator at the end of my_stream missing tehn increase the size of array of my_stream.