# Weird characters on char array to string conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I know there's a lot information and threads about char array to string conversion, but I tried a lot of "solutions" without any success. I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193711/char-array-to-string-conversion-results-in-strange-characters-sockets) which is the closest to my issue but didn't work either.

I have the following code:

```
recvlen = recvfrom(s, recvbuf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
if (recvlen < 0) {
    printf("socket() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
}

string msgrcv(recvbuf, recvlen);
printf("String : %s \n", msgrcv);   //Prints the weird characters
printf("Array : %s \n", recvbuf);  //Prints ok the result
```

Any ideas what I'm missing or is wrong?

Comment: @joe Please add your output.

Comment: In that case -> `printf` can't handle the C++ string.

Comment: it's c++, I've got "using namespace std;" on the top of the code, the code compiles and works.

Comment: Should be `printf("String : %s \n", msgrcv.c_str())` as `%s` expects a pointer to char array, not a `std::string` object.

Comment: use `cout << msgrcv` instead of `printf`. The weird characters should disappear, along with a warning that I'm sure you are getting.

Comment: Ok, thanks, is as simpler as to use cout instead printf, problem solved. Sorry I'm switching from C to C++ and I'm confusing the syntax

Comment: @joe Free tip: Gradually injecting C++ code into C code will not result in very good C++ code and so an important step in switching from C to C++ is to unlearn C idioms and conventions.

Answer (score 4):

Your strange characters being printed are a result of undefined behavior.

```
printf("String : %s \n", msgrcv);
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to a nul terminated character array (C-string). You pass a `std::string` (assuming a nasty `using namespace std;` somewhere).

To match data type to format specifier, use `std::string::c_str`:

```
printf("String : %s \n", msgrcv.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` format specifier `%s` requires that the argument must be a pointer (`char*`) to a null-terminated character array. You didn't pass a `char*`, but a `string`.

If `string` happens to be `std::string`, then you can get a pointer to the null terminated character string using the `c_str` member function. Or you could use a stream:

```
std::cout << "String : " << msgrcv << '\n';
```